# Проблема с созданием функции-члена, принимающей пользовательский класс

Tags: c++, qt5

Есть свой класс, наследующий QGroupBox (не знаю, важно ли), и другой свой класс, просто хранящий данные и несколько функций к ним. Мне нужно передать в метод первого класса экземпляр второго.

MattyGroupBox.h

```
#ifndef MATTYGROUPBOX_H
#define MATTYGROUPBOX_H

    public QGroupBox
{
public:
    MattyGroupBox();
    //void fillFrame(MattyNote & ThisNote);
    ~MattyGroupBox();
private:
    void buildFrame();
    QLabel* NoteTitleLabel;
    QLabel* NoteTypeLabel;
    QLabel* NoteCrTimeAndDateLabel;
    QLabel* NoteEventTimeAndDateLabel;
    QLabel* NoteTextLabel;
    QSpacerItem* horizontalSpacer_1;
    QSpacerItem* horizontalSpacer_2;
    QSpacerItem* verticalSpacer;
    QPushButton* editNoteButton;
    QPushButton* deleteNoteButton;
    QHBoxLayout* horizontalLayout_1;
    QHBoxLayout* horizontalLayout_2;
    QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout;
    QGridLayout *gridLayout;

};

#endif // MATTYGROUPBOX_H
```

MattyGroupBox.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MattyGroupBox.h"
#include "MattyNote.h"


MattyGroupBox::MattyGroupBox()
{
    buildFrame();
}

//void MattyGroupBox::fillFrame(MattyNote & ThisNote)
//{
    //NoteTitleLabel->setText(ThisNote.getTitle());
    //NoteTypeLabel->setText(ThisNote.getType());
    //NoteTextLabel->setText(ThisNote.getText());    
//}

void MattyGroupBox::buildFrame()
{
    // тут очень много того, из-за чего потребовалось наследовать класс
    // добавление элементов Qt

}

MattyGroupBox::~MattyGroupBox()
{
    delete NoteTitleLabel;
    delete NoteTypeLabel;
    delete NoteCrTimeAndDateLabel;
    delete NoteEventTimeAndDateLabel;
    delete NoteTextLabel;
    delete horizontalSpacer_1;
    delete horizontalSpacer_2;
    delete verticalSpacer;
    delete editNoteButton;
    delete deleteNoteButton;
    delete horizontalLayout_1;
    delete horizontalLayout_2;
    delete verticalLayout;
    delete gridLayout;
}
```

Если раскомментить метод, вылезут ошибки:

```
Error   C2511   'void MattyGroupBox::fillFrame(MattyNote &)': overloaded member function not found in 'MattyGroupBox'
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'MattyNote'
```

MattyNote.h

```
#ifndef MATTYNOTE_H
#define MATTYNOTE_H

#include "MattyTime.h"

class MattyNote
{
public:
    MattyNote();
    ~MattyNote();
    void setTitle(const QString & Title);
    void setType(const QString & TypeName);
    void setType(int TypeId);
    void setText(const QString & Text);
    void setEventTime(const QString & EventTime); // Warning! Input format must be: 00:00
    void setEventDate(const QString & EventDate); // Warning! Input format must be: 00.00.0000
    QString getTitle();
    QString getType();
    QString getText();
    QString getEventTime(); // Format: 00:00
    QString getEventDate(); // Format: 00.00.0000
    QString getCrTime(); // Format: 00:00
    QString getCrDate(); // Format: 00.00.0000
    int getTypeId();
    TimeAndDate* getEventTimeAndDate(); // Returns a pointer to TimeAndDate structure containing ints
    TimeAndDate* getCrTimeAndDate(); // Returns a pointer to the TimeAndDate structure containing ints
private:
    int NoteTypeId;
    QString NoteTitle;
    QString NoteType;
    QString NoteText;
    QString NoteEventTime; // Format: 00:00
    QString NoteEventDate; // Format: 00.00.0000
    MattyTime* EventTimeAndDate;  // Any unspecified part equals -1
    MattyTime* CrTimeAndDate;  // Automaticly set in constructor of MattyNote
};

#endif // MATTYNOTE_H
```

MattyNote.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MattyNote.h"
#include "Constants.h"
#include "DbManager.h"

MattyNote::MattyNote()
{
    EventTimeAndDate = new MattyTime();
    EventTimeAndDate->setUserTimeAndDateNull();
    CrTimeAndDate = new MattyTime();
    MattyTime::updateCurrTime();
    CrTimeAndDate->UserTimeAndDate = MattyTime::CurrTime;
}

MattyNote::~MattyNote()
{
    delete EventTimeAndDate;
    delete CrTimeAndDate;
}

void MattyNote::setTitle(const QString & Title)
{
    NoteTitle = Title;
}

void MattyNote::setType(const QString & TypeName)
{
    DbManager* MattyNotesDbManager = new DbManager("MattyNotes.sqlite");
    NoteTypeId = MattyNotesDbManager->getTypeId(TypeName);
    NoteType = TypeName;
    delete MattyNotesDbManager;
}

void MattyNote::setType(int TypeId)
{
    DbManager* MattyNotesDbManager = new DbManager("MattyNotes.sqlite");
    NoteType = MattyNotesDbManager->getTypeName(TypeId);
    NoteTypeId = TypeId;
    delete MattyNotesDbManager;
}

void MattyNote::setText(const QString & Text)
{
    NoteText = Text;
}

void MattyNote::setEventTime(const QString & EventTime)
{
    if (EventTime.length() == Constants::TimeQStringLength && EventTime[2] == Constants::TimeSeparator)
    {
        NoteEventTime = EventTime;
        QStringList TimeTemp = EventTime.split(Constants::TimeSeparator);
        EventTimeAndDate->UserTimeAndDate->hour = TimeTemp[0].toInt();
        EventTimeAndDate->UserTimeAndDate->minute = TimeTemp[1].toInt();
        EventTimeAndDate->UserTimeAndDate->second = 0;
    }
}

void MattyNote::setEventDate(const QString & EventDate)
{
    if (EventDate.length() == Constants::DateQStringLength &&
        EventDate[Constants::PositionOfFirstDateSeparator] == Constants::DateSeparator
        && EventDate[Constants::PositionOfSecondDateSeparator] == Constants::DateSeparator)
    {
        NoteEventDate = EventDate;
        QStringList DateTemp = EventDate.split(Constants::DateSeparator);
        EventTimeAndDate->UserTimeAndDate->day = DateTemp[0].toInt();
        EventTimeAndDate->UserTimeAndDate->month = DateTemp[1].toInt();
        EventTimeAndDate->UserTimeAndDate->year = DateTemp[2].toInt();
        EventTimeAndDate->setUserDayOfWeek();
    }
}

QString MattyNote::getTitle()
{
    return NoteTitle;
}

QString MattyNote::getType()
{
    return NoteType;
}

QString MattyNote::getText()
{
    return NoteText;
}

QString MattyNote::getEventTime()
{
    return NoteEventTime;
}

QString MattyNote::getEventDate()
{
    return NoteEventDate;
}

QString MattyNote::getCrTime()
{
    return CrTimeAndDate->PrintUserTime();
}

QString MattyNote::getCrDate()
{
    return CrTimeAndDate->PrintUserDate();
}

int MattyNote::getTypeId()
{
    return NoteTypeId;
}

TimeAndDate * MattyNote::getEventTimeAndDate()
{
    return EventTimeAndDate->UserTimeAndDate;
}

TimeAndDate * MattyNote::getCrTimeAndDate()
{
    return CrTimeAndDate->UserTimeAndDate;
}
```

stdafx.h не включает заголовков вообще, Constants.h, DbManager.h, MattyTime.h и их cpp тоже не отправляют никуда.

Собственно, в чем тут может быть дело? Вообще в проекте по 10 файлов заголовков и кода, если еще что-то надо - выложу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема, видимо, состоит в том, что при объявлении класса `QGroupBox` компилятор не видит объявления имени `MattyNote`.

Поэтому либо включите заголовок `MattyNote.h` в заголовок `MattyGroupBox.h`, либо в заголовке `MattyGroupBox.h` в объявлении класса напишите

```
void fillFrame( class MattyNote & ThisNote);
                ^^^^
```

Или перед объявлением класса напишите

```
class MattyNote;
```

Comment: Спасибо) `void fillFrame( class MattyNote & ThisNote);` сработало

Comment: @Matty Не за что. Мы, начинающие программисты, должны помогать друг другу.:)

Comment: Ну, я-то начинающий, это да)

Comment: @Matty А я даже и не приступал к программированию. Я лишь отвечаю на вопросы.:)